# How to go from one view controller to another view controller through tab bar controller when Click a button in the first view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uistoryboard

I am developing one i pad application using story board.In my storyboard i have tab bar controller and another  4 view controllers are connected to tab bar controller are tab items.I have one button in the first view controller.If i click that button i need to display 4th view controller.If i give a direct segue from first view controller to 4th view controller using

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueIdentifier" sender:nil];
```

the 4th view controller is appeared but the tab bar display at the bottom is disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like this when the button is pressed...

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3];
```

This will tell the tab bar controller to change the selected tab.

Comment: Hmm... you could possibly add a category to UITabBarController with a method something like ... `- (void)selectTabAtIndex:(NSInteger)index withString:(NSString *)string;` this would then switch to the tab and then pass in the correct value to it.

Comment: @user3762713 you might be able to do this anyway. `UITabBarController` has a property `viewControllers` that contains them all. You could get at it `viewControllers[3]` and pass the data in before switching.

Comment: I put one more question would you please help me to solve the issue.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446429/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-when-add-an-unwind-function-to-view-contr

Answer (score 0):

Try use it->

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SegueIdentifier"]) {
        [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3];
    }
}
```