# Linker command failed with exit code 1 When add an unwind function to view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am developing one iPad application using storyboard. In my application I have a popup and a view controller. If I add a function like:

```
-(IBAction)unwindCouponPaymentToOrderdetailsView:(UIStoryboardSegue *)unwindSegue{
}
```

My application fails to compile and shows this error:

```
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).
```

I don't know where is the error. I check two or three times After this code will add to my view controller  the compilation become failed. I remove the above mentioned code then again try to compile the application that time also same error is coming. Then I check out the latest code from SVN do the work up to this stage all are working fine if add this function to the view controller again application become failed. I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: Please update the question with the entire error message that you get.

Comment: @GoGreen build Faild Apple Mac -O Linker error Linker Command failed with exit code 1(use -v to see invocation)

Comment: link error usually occurs when some file that you reference goes missing from xcode. There will be a description of the file name along with that error. Please post a screenshot of the error.